# Как передать ImageView из Activity в Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-imageview

Для создания OnBoard'a использую активити OnBoardActivity, которая передает в фрагмент OnBoardFragment текст ссылаясь на текстовые ресурсы.

Код активити:

```
class OnBoardActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    val fragment1 = OnBoardFragment()
    val fragment2 = OnBoardFragment()
    val fragment3 = OnBoardFragment()

    lateinit var adapter : myPagerAdapter
    lateinit var activity : Activity

    lateinit var preference : SharedPreferences
    val pref_show_intro = "Intro"




    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_on_board)
        activity = this
        preference = getSharedPreferences("OnBoardSlide", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

        if (!preference.getBoolean(pref_show_intro, true)) {
            startActivity(Intent(activity, TrainActivity::class.java))
            finish()
        }

        val string_fragment1 : String = getString(R.string.on_board_text_one)
        val string_fragment2 : String = getString(R.string.on_board_text_two)
        val string_fragment3 : String = getString(R.string.on_board_text_three)

        fragment1.setTitle(string_fragment1)
        fragment2.setTitle(string_fragment2)
        fragment3.setTitle(string_fragment3)

        adapter = myPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager)
        adapter.list.add(fragment1)
        adapter.list.add(fragment2)
        adapter.list.add(fragment3)

        view_pager.adapter = adapter
        btn_next.setOnClickListener {
            view_pager.currentItem++
        }

        // skip OnBoard go To Next Activity
        btn_skip.setOnClickListener {
            goToNextActivity()
        }

        view_pager.addOnPageChangeListener(object : ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener{
            override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int) {

            }

            override fun onPageScrolled(position: Int, positionOffset: Float, positionOffsetPixels: Int) {

            }

            override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
                if (position == adapter.list.size - 1) {
                    //lastPage
                    btn_next.text = "DONE"
                    btn_next.setOnClickListener {
                        goToNextActivity()
                    }
                } else {
                    // has next
                    btn_next.text = "NEXT"
                    btn_next.setOnClickListener {
                        view_pager.currentItem++
                    }
                }

                when(view_pager.currentItem) {
                    0 -> {
                        indicator1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK)
                        indicator2.setTextColor(Color.GRAY)
                        indicator3.setTextColor(Color.GRAY)
                    }
                    1 -> {
                        indicator1.setTextColor(Color.GRAY)
                        indicator2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK)
                        indicator3.setTextColor(Color.GRAY)
                    }
                    2 -> {
                        indicator1.setTextColor(Color.GRAY)
                        indicator2.setTextColor(Color.GRAY)
                        indicator3.setTextColor(Color.BLACK)
                    }
                }
            }

        })
    }

    fun goToNextActivity() {
        startActivity(Intent(activity, TrainActivity::class.java))
        finish()
        val editor = preference.edit()
        editor.putBoolean(pref_show_intro, false)
        editor.apply()
    }

    class myPagerAdapter(manager: FragmentManager) : FragmentPagerAdapter(manager) {

        val list: MutableList<Fragment> = ArrayList()

        override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
            return list[position]
        }

        override fun getCount(): Int {
            return list.size
        }

    }
}
```

Код фрагмента:

```
class OnBoardFragment : Fragment() {

    var pageTitle : String = ""

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_on_board, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        on_board_text_view.text = pageTitle

    }

    fun setTitle(title : String) {
        pageTitle = title

    }
}
```

Как я понимаю надо создать функцию в активити, которая будет принимать ImageView и передавать в фрагмент, а уже в фрагменте для каждого случая, прописать свой ImageView. Но как технически реализовать такую функцию?

Comment: А, не проще выполнить все действия сразу во фрагменте? А, ещё лучше вынести их отдельный класс и из UI просто дёргать его методы?

Comment: Возможно Вы правы. Можно вообще создать несколько imageview и передавать их по очереди на экраны, но это колхоз у меня получится. Хотелось бы все-таки понять, как можно написать функцию, которая будет позволять выбрать какое изображение в него загружать. С текстом получилось все, а вот с изображением никак не выходит

Comment: сами View категорически не рекомендуется передавать за пределы контроллера (активити или фрагмента), но вы можете передавать их содержимое, в случае ImageView - ID картинки из ресурсов или имя файла, в зависимости, как хранятся ваши картинки

Comment: @pavlofff я не хочу передавать view. Вот к примеру с текстом, у меня в фрагменте есть TextView, который изначально пустой. Экземпляров фрагментов (не уверен, что правильно выражаюсь) у меня три штуки. В каждый из них я передаю через строковые ресурсы определенный текст. В фрагменте так же есть ImageView, вот не могу понять как мне каждому экземпляру передать свое изображение (изображения хранятся в drawable)

Comment: передавайте в фрагмент ID изображения (как R.drawable.image1 - это число типа int)  так же, как вы передаете текст. Полученный ID присвлйте в ImageView в фрагменте - `imageView.setImageResource(ID)`, где ID - то, что вы получите из активити (ID = R.drawable.image1)

Answer (score 1):

View не передается, если я правильно вас понял вам из активити надо сказать фрагменту что показывать. Если так, тогда в фрагменте создаете одну ImageView, а из активити во фрагмент передаете какую-то константу (например 0, 1, 2) и проверяете что пришло. Если 0 - сетите одно изображение, если 1 - другое, и т.д.

Comment: как вариант, можно передавать ID изображения (как R.drawable.image1, по факту число типа int)/ Это упросит логику отображения в фрагменте, особенно, если изображений много.

Comment: ну проверку того что надо показывать так или иначе надо где-то делать и судя по всему архитектурой тут и не пахнет, поэтому как по мне большой разницы нет. Но если в активити мы сразу знаем что надо показывать, то передавать id ресурса таки лучше.